What is the anti-trust argument made by X Corp's recent lawsuit against advertisers that boycotted X/Twitter
X Corp. has filed a lawsuit against the various advertisers that boycotted X/twitter after Musk took over.  The articles I found didn't elaborate much on the lawsuit but what little they do say leaves me wondering what law the advertisers allegedly violated.
I know It's an anti-trust lawsuit, alleging that the companies conspired against X.  However, even if one were to agree that this was a conspiracy rather than multiple companies making independent decisions due to brand safety I'm not sure I understand why that would be illegal.  I know the Sherman Antitrust Act prevents conspiring to fix wages or prices, but it seems a stretch to say that applies to pulling advertisements.
So a few related questions.

What anti-trust law is allegedly being broken?
Would the law be broken if one accepted the claim of companies conspiring against x/twitter?
what proof is presented of the alleged conspiracy?


The article you linked to says that it will likely be difficult for him to prove this, according to legal experts.

Here is an interesting read on it https://www.rollingstone.com/culture/culture-features/elon-musk-twitter-advertisers-lawsuit-joke-1235074957/

This case, briefly quoted in the rolling stone article above, seems to give him much better odds than I expected.

I am somewhat confused by the events here. 1) The CEO of X tells advertisers to leave. 2) Advertisers do as the CEO of X told them to and leave. 3) X sues the advertisers for leaving. Huh?

While this is a good question, one shouldn't confuse the legal argument as being at all related to Musk's goals . The non-profit coalition of major advertisers that he sued, Global Alliance for Responsible Media, has already shutdown because it cannot afford to fight the lawsuit. This is similar to Musk's lawsuits against other non-profits such as Media Matters and the Center for Countering Digital Hate. The arguments his lawyers make may be academically interesting to consider, but are ultimately moot. No matter what a judge rules on the merits, Musk has already silenced his critics.

The U.S. Justice Department describes what constitutes a conspiracy in restraint of trade:

Price fixing, bid rigging and market allocation are among the group of
antitrust offenses that are considered “per se” unreasonable
restraints of trade. The courts have reasoned that these practices,
which invariably have the effect of raising prices to consumers, have
no legitimate justification and lack any redeeming competitive purpose
and should, therefore, be considered unlawful without any further
analysis of their reasonableness, economic justification, or other
factors. For most other antitrust offenses, the courts have
established an analytical approach labeled the “rule of reason.” Under
the “rule of reason,” the courts must undertake an extensive
evidentiary study of (1) whether the practice in question in fact is
likely to have a significant anticompetitive effect in a relevant
market and (2) whether there are any procompetitive justifications
relating to the restraint. Under the “rule of reason,” if any
anticompetitive harm would be outweighed by the practice’s
procompetitive effects, the practice is not unlawful. Virtually all
antitrust offenses likely to be prosecuted by a United States
Attorney’s office will be governed by the “per se” rule.

Establishing that this is an illegal restraint of trade under the "rule of reason" would be challenging for Musk in this case. There are legitimate business reasons that are not anti-competitive to drop Twitter such as the tarnished brand image. Marketing decisions are particularly open to "soft" considerations like that.
It also requires a showing of a conspiracy between the alleged participants as opposed to independent decision making, as explained at the same link, which would be at least challenging in this case:

Conspiracy or Agreement: The conspiracy or agreement to fix prices, rig bids or allocate markets is the key element of a Sherman
Act criminal case. In effect, the conspiracy must comprise an
agreement, understanding or meeting of the minds between at least two
competitors or potential competitors, for the purpose or with the
effect of unreasonably restraining trade. The agreement itself is what
constitutes the offense; overt acts in furtherance of the conspiracy
are not essential elements of the offense and need not be pleaded or
proven in a Sherman Act case.
In a Sherman Act criminal case, general intent must be proven.
Customarily, however, proof of the existence of a price fixing, or bid
rigging or market allocation agreement is sufficient to establish
intent to do what the defendants agreed among themselves to do.
The agreement need not be embodied in express or formal contractual
statements. It must merely constitute some form of mutual
understanding that the parties will combine their efforts for a
common, unlawful purpose. The ultimate success of the venture is
immaterial as long as the agreement is in fact formed.
Knowingly Joining the Conspiracy: To find the defendant acted knowingly, it must be shown that the defendant acted voluntarily and
intentionally rather than because of a mistake, accident, or other
innocent reason. The defendant must have joined the conspiracy with
the intent to assist or advance the object or purpose of the
conspiracy. The government need not show that the defendant knew all
the details or members of the conspiracy nor that the defendant
participated in all the conspiratorial acts. Also, it is not necessary
for the defendant to have participated in the origination of the
conspiracy. Of course, mere knowledge of the conspiracy without
participation in the conspiracy does not make a defendant a member of
the conspiracy. In addition, a defendant who knowingly directs another
person to participate in the conspiracy is responsible for the conduct
s/he directed just as if s/he directly participated in the conduct. If
a defendant is shown to have joined a conspiracy, the defendant is
presumed to remain a member of the conspiracy until the conspiracy has
been completed or abandoned or until the defendant has withdrawn from
the conspiracy.


Marketing decisions may also be owed added deference due to First Amendment considerations. Congress cannot simply order a company to market itself in a particular way.

@Kevin Good point.

@Kevin They could be ordered to dissolve the illegal conspiracy and to pay Twitter damages, though.

@nick012000 That would require that not advertising on twitter was not some kind of speech against twitter's conduct. If it is some kind of speech, then it falls under 1st amendment protection and no damages can be awarded.

@nick012000 A First Amendment defense would be a bar to liability of any kind.

What exactly constitutes "market allocation?" While it doesn't sound like any price fixing or big rigging is being alleged, just the plain language of "market allocation" sounds like it might apply here, but I'm not sure what the legal definition of it is.

@reirab An example of market allocation would be Albertsons conspiring with Kroger to let Albertsons have all of the Western suburbs of Denver while Kroger got all of the Eastern suburbs of Denver.

@reirab Or think of towns in Germany: For a long time (and in most cases still), you would not find both a Burger King and a McDonalds in the same town but for the really big ones (Berlin, Hamburg, Munich, Cologne). That could be a conspiracy where the towns are allocated to one or the other... but it's just that having more options in most towns would lead to reduced profits for both franchises, as the market just isn't large enough for both in one town and they are too close in their offered foods to draw in people wanting different food.

Isn't joining GARM and agreeing to follow its edicts "knowingly joining the conspiracy"?

The claim is here: X Corp v. World Federation of Advertisers et al.
The alleged anti-trust violation is restraint of trade, in particular, a "group boycott" akin to price-fixing or other activities that limit a party's ability to enter into transactions. ohwilleke sets out what is required to establish this kind of violation.
X Corp. alleges that:

As a condition of GARM membership, GARM’s members agree to adopt, implement, and enforce GARM’s brand safety standards, including by withholding advertising
from social media platforms deemed by GARM to be non-compliant with the brand safety
standards. ...
...
Pursuant to the conspiracy, major brand advertisers, including the advertiser
Defendants and dozens of non-defendant co-conspirators, agreed to and did, abruptly and in
lockstep, boycott Twitter by discontinuing entirely or substantially reducing their previously
substantial advertising purchases from Twitter.
...
The Defendants and their co-conspirators have market power, called monopsony power on the buy side, in the relevant market, controlling ninety percent or more of spending in
the relevant market.
...
Due to the boycott of
Twitter, prices charged by Twitter for advertising declined substantially beginning in November
2022 and remain well below those charged by X’s closest competitors in the social media
advertising market.
...
As a result of the boycott, X became a less effective competitor to other social
media platforms in the sale of digital advertising and in competing for user engagement on its
platform. By sharply curtailing its revenues, the boycott has reduced X’s ability to invest in new
or improved functionality, thus harming the consumers who use X’s platform.

You also ask "what proof is presented?" In a pleading, it is inappropriate to submit proof. The pleadings only contain alleged facts that the party intends to prove. The proof comes later. You can read the alleged facts in the pleading linked above.
There are many ways to prove alleged facts. See How do you prove a fact at issue in litigation?

And, in fairness, the claim probably isn't a strong one and verges on frivolous.

Thank you for your answer, but you still didn't cover my second question entirely.  Even if there was a conspiracy, is it against the law?  The companies don't seem to have anything to gain from not advertising with twitter other then brand safety.  Does group boycott require the companies to be trying to fix prices, stifle competition, or otherwise have a financial gain?  I'm not an expert in this, but I'd think that a conspiracy that was not for financial gain for the company wouldn't actually be illegal?  Note I don't think there was a conspiracy either.

@dsollen Some of the sued companies are ad-distributors, they have nothing to gain from putting their customer's ads on twitter but to lose their customers. They gain retaining their customers from cutting out twitter. However, Twitter wood need to show somehow that the companies did coordinate their action in some way as a form of Group Boycott. If they all independently saw "Advertizing there is bad business, our customers would run", that is not illegal.

@dsollen That's for the court to decide. Musk's lawyers presumably think they have a case (or they weren't able to convince Musk otherwise).

Musk seems to be claiming that joining GARM and agreeing to follow its policies is that coordination. They're not making independent decisions, they're implementing the group guidelines.

If the advertisers were boycotting X to reach more favorable prices that would be something that should be illegal in my opinion, but boycotting X because they deem the platform brand-unsafe sounds to me like a very legitimate reason and it implies there is something X can do about that isn't tied to how much they'd be able to charge for ad space. It just seems they decided they don't want to be brand-safe - and in my interpretation should have expected and were okay with advertisers pulling spending on their platform - in favor of letting everyone speak their mind on their platform.

@Jen None. Just commented on the "alleged anti-trust violation is restraint of trade, in particular, a "group boycott" akin to price-fixing" part. It will be interesting to see how a court is going to rule. Or if you can or want to expand: Can the defendants argue that the boycot does not anti-trust law because it isn't done for the reason of price-fixing?

@ohwilleke - that didn't age well. :)

@Mayo Pretty spineless of them.

@suchiuomizu - I'm not an attorney. What made them cave? They were afraid of what would come out in discovery?  They're a powerful group. They don't cave without reason.
